# Communications between master and workers: is it a better practice to use http requests or scp files and monitor file creation?

Tags: python, http, mapreduce, python-watchdog

#### [Background]:

I'm implementing a simplified version of mapreduce framework in `python`. Basically `master` will assign a file to each `worker`, and `worker` will process the file and send the result back. After receiving all results from `workers` `master` will aggregate results, i.e. act as a single reducer.

#### [My Question]:

My college and I had different opinions on how to implement the communications between `master` and `workers`.

**My way is to open http servers on `master` and `workers`**(python has built-in http server `SimpleHttpServer`). Basically `master` will send a `post` request with the file as data, and `worker` will acknowledge the file. After processing the file, the `worker` will send another `post` request with the result (json object) to `master`.

**But my college thinks I should use `scp` to transfer file from `master` to `workers`, and let `workers` write result into a file.** `workers` should use `scp` to transfer the result file to `master` (for example, in a certain directory), and let `master` periodically check that directory to see if there is a result file.

#### [My Reasoning]:

The reasons I think http servers is a better solution are as follows:

- It's possible to use temporary folder and no need to tell worker a specific directory to place files.
- If monitoring on file creation, one has to make sure the result file from `worker` get copied to `master` *after* watchdog starts.
- Monitoring file creation may have to deal with stale files, e.g. files from last run. This may require some sort of timestamp, which I think is a little hacky.

I guess the major con for using http servers is that python does not have very good built-in http server. But I still feel that transferring file and monitoring file creation is not as clean as using `http requests`.

Any suggestions will be appreciated! And also if possible please do not mark this as "**mainly opinion-based**". I've tried to provided as much info as I can and I think at least for this certain scenario one solution is better than the other.

#### [More info]

- Each file is less than 100 MB. (Most of them are roughly 40 MB)
- File transfer is on private network, and the file content is not sensitive. I guess there is no need to encrypt them.
- Results are much smaller than the input file.
- There are roughly 20 workers, and file numbers are roughly 40.

Comment: `scp` is not a standards-defined tool. Even if one *was* going to use a file transfer tool that runs over the SSH protocol, it wouldn't be my first choice -- `sftp`'s wire protocol is much more closely defined (and gives the client very explicit control over how things are written on the server -- f/e, whether a create-and-rename pattern is used). And if you're doing that from Python, you have the Paramiko library.

Comment: ...that said, "best practice" questions are generally considered too broad to be on-topic here; see f/e discussion @ https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296542/are-is-it-a-good-practice-questions-off-topic-or-opinion-based

Comment: Also, note that code formatting is *only for code*, not non-code technical terms. `http servers` is not source code. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254990/when-should-code-formatting-be-used-for-non-code-text

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the comment I'll modify my post. And I know generally "best practice" questions are too-board so I'm trying to provide a much more concrete scenario. And thanks for the suggestions on `sftp`. But I guest what I am more interested in, if true, why monitoring file is better than using http requests in this particular circumstance.

Comment: I don't actually think there's a sufficiently compelling argument to make *either* universally or canonically correct -- which makes this a soft/fuzzy/opinion-based question. Mind you, switching to HTTP doesn't make your problems go away -- you're either going to have content retrieved unnecessarily, or still be relying on mtimes to be reflected in the cache headers to tell the client when it can stick with the content it already has (if you're using a HTTP client smart enough to even do that!).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I guess I'm wondering why monitoring file creation is a better option. Anyway if this is too opinion-based I'll close it soon.

Comment: Personally, between the two, I'd go with your proposed architecture -- but that's as a matter of opinion/gut/preference. Sure, I could come up with some technical justifications (about, say, keeping your implementation operating over well-defined protocols so components can be swapped out -- there's nothing well-defined about `scp`), but they'd be just that -- post-hoc justifications.